# Java only allow two drawn circles to be selected at a time, how to unselect

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, select, unselect

Hey so I've got 20 circles displayed on a screen, I want the user to be able to select only two circles and be able to unselect circles but still only have maximum 2 circles selected. I know how to allow it to only select two circles at a time but not unselect AND how to unselect when only one circle is allowed, I'm just confused now.

This code allows only two circles to be selected but I cannot unselect the circles

```
Figur vald1 = null, vald2 = null;

Figur fig = (Figur)mev.getSource();

if (vald1 == null){
            vald1 = fig;
            vald1.setVald(true);
            }
            else if (vald2 == null && fig1 != vald1){
            vald2 = fig;
            vald2.setVald(true);
            }
```

and this code allows me to select one circle at a time, and unselect it but not select two circles

```
if (vald1 != null)
        vald1.setVald(false);

        if (vald1 == fig)
        vald1 = null;
        else{
        fig.setVald(true);
        fig.requestFocusInWindow();
        vald1 = fig;
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Figur vald1 = null, vald2 = null;

Figur fig = (Figur)mev.getSource();

vald1 = vald2;
vald2 = fig;
```

Now vald1 and vald2 hold the 2 more recent circles, with vald1 being the older of the two.

You could also use a list, that way you can do as many as you like:

```
List<Figur> selected = new ArrayList<Figur>();
final static NUM_TO_KEEP = 2;

Figur fig = (Figur)mev.getSource();

selected.push(fig);

// This trims the list to only maintain the NUM_TO_KEEP elements.
while(selected.length() > NUM_TO_KEEP) {
    selected.remove(NUM_TO_KEEP);
}
```

Comment: I think you answered the question.